# Any library in java to convert JSON to XML and vice versa in following format?

Tags: java, json, xml

Is there any java library which converts the JSON data to XML with attribute support and vice versa.

**Input JSON**

```
{
    "test": "123",
    "PersonInfoShipTo": {
        "@AddressID": "",
        "@ZipCode": "fdsafsa"
    },
    "OrderLineItems": [
        {
            "@OrderLineItemId": "OrderLineItemId"
        },
        {
            "@OrderLineItemId": "OrderLineItemId"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
    <OrderLineItems>
        <OrderLineItem OrderLineItemId="OrderLineItemId" />
        <OrderLineItem OrderLineItemId="OrderLineItemId" />
    </OrderLineItems>
    <PersonInfoShipTo AddressID="" ZipCode="fdsafsa" />
    <test>123</test>
</Order>
```

Comment: Are you looking for libraries that do precisely the transformation in this exact way? Or are you looking for a library that would allow you to implement this easily? What did you try already to do this and what problem did you encounter?

Comment: No I don't need exactly in thus way. But it should support to create attributes in XML and also the support for array in jsons. I tried to solve this problem using xpath  but that doesn't solve problem in case of as array.

Comment: I think you should post exactly what you tried and where it fell apart. Post the code that you attempted.